# Displacement Vector and resultant vector

Tags: kinematics, displacement

I am struggling with the concept of displacement. From my understanding displacement can be found for 1D motion along the x-axis as $\Delta x= x_{f}-x_{i}$. For example someone walks $1\,\mathrm{m}$ to the left then $1\,\mathrm{m}$ to the right then $2\,\mathrm{m}$ to the left and finally $3\,\mathrm{m}$ to the right. I know that I can find the net displacement by adding them all up as $-1+1-2+3$ and get $1\;\mathrm{m}$ to the right as my resultant displacement. My question is why can't I use $\Delta x$ and use the $3$ as my final position and $0$ as my initial position? I know that it clearly doesn't give me the correct answer but why does that not work?

Comment: Think about if you went 50 steps left and then 1 right. Could you use 1 minus zero? The three minus zero gives your most recent displacement, not the total displacement

Comment: I get what you are saying but I thought that displacement only cared about your final position and your initial position as opposed to distance which cares about the total distance traveled. That's why you could have a displacement of zero when moving back and forth but your distance would not be zero

Comment: If you never got to the position 3 meters to the right, it isn’t your final position, right?

Answer (score 4):

Responding to your question and follow up comment, displacement is indeed final position minus initial position. But in your example, the numbers you are listing are in fact displacements, not positions.

Let us number your positions as follows:

\begin{array} {r|r} \hline x_0 & 0 \\  x_1 & -1 \\ x_2 & 0 \\  x_3 & -2 \\  x_4 & 1 \\   \end{array}

Those are the positions after each step.

The displacements after each step are given by $\Delta x = x_{current} - x_{previous}$, or in other words:

\begin{array} {r|r} \hline \Delta x_1 & -1 \\ \Delta x_2 & 1 \\ \Delta  x_3 & -2 \\ \Delta  x_4 & 3 \\   \end{array}

Which are the numbers you presented.  You can easily verify that the current position is the cumulative sum of all previous displacements, and that any given displacement is the difference between the current and previous positions.  The *total* displacement is $x_4-x_0 = 1$, but subtracting the individual displacements like $\Delta x_4 - \Delta x_1$ does not give anything meaningful.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I didn't realize that the distance when given like that is a displacement not a position. So when they give you a vector let's say $\vec{A}= 2 \hat{i} + 3 \hat{j}$ is that a position then?

Comment: @mach123 That's very very subjective. $\overrightarrow{A}$ could represent any vector quantity. The question must mention/give a hint on what it represents, as in position, velocity, or whatsoever. The units _might_ be helpful, but are not enough (position and displacement have same units)